# sys.argv when calling python with -c

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, argparse

Consider the following short python (3.8) snippet:

```py
import subprocess


def call_subprocess_command(*command: str):
    with subprocess.Popen(args=command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True) as process:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
            print(line)



call_subprocess_command("python", "-c", "import sys; print(sys.argv)", "--test", "foo")
```

This will print `['-c', '--test', 'foo']`. I want it to print only `['--test', 'foo']`.

I need this because I am dynamically computing a command to be run inside a docker container.
However, the cli parser of the code that is called always breaks because it receives the "-c" argument, which it does not know how to deal with:

```py
call_subprocess_command("python", "-c", 
"import argparse; parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(); parser.add_argument('test'); print(parser.parse_args())",
 "--test", "foo")
```

This results in the usage being printed to stderr, and it parses "-c" as the value for "test":

```
usage: -c [-h] test
-c: error: unrecognized arguments: --test
```

My current work-around is using keyword-only arguments ("--test"), but I'd really like to get rid of that "-c" if possible.

```py
call_subprocess_command("python", "-c", 
"import argparse; parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(); parser.add_argument('--test'); print(parser.parse_args())",
 "--test", "foo")
```

This results in what I want:

`Namespace(test='foo')`

I do not quite understand why this works, because it now seems to ignore the "-c".
If I add another parameter that it does not know about, e.g. "--bar", it crashes again, even though "-c" is also a parameter that it doesn't know about:

```
call_subprocess_command("python", "-c",
 "import argparse; parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(); parser.add_argument('--test'); print(parser.parse_args())",
 "--test", "foo", "--bar")
```

```
usage: -c [-h] [--test TEST]
-c: error: unrecognized arguments: --bar
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I get rid of the "-c" argument being present in the subprocess' `sys.argv`?
2. Why can argparse sometimes ignore "-c", and sometimes not?

Comment: Remember that `sys.argv[0]` is always the name the current executable was invoked under (that's true at the operating-system level too, so programs can behave differently depending on what name they were started under). So it's normal and expected to ignore it for purposes of parsing arguments, *except* in error messages (where you expect the message to start with the executable name you currently used).

Comment: That's a facility for programs like `busybox`, which can be started under hundreds of names, depending on whether you want it to act like `ls` or `cp` or `sh` or so forth. Why the decision was made to have `python -c '...'` put `-c` in the `argv[0]` slot is one I'd want to search through the Python ticket tracker to find a justification, unless one is already given is a comment in the source.

Comment: That said, it's not "sometimes ignore "-c", and sometimes not"; argparse **always** ignores `argv[0]` outside the printing-of-help context, which is just what it ought to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments, `argparse` uses `sys.argv[0]` as the `prog` and parses `sys.argv[1:]`.

This may be clearer if I specify the `prog` parameter, which then replaces the default '-c':

```
1119:~/mypy$ python3 -c 'import argparse; p=argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="PROG");print(p.parse_args())' --test foobar
usage: PROG [-h]
PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: --test foobar
```

In normal script usage, `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script.  Here the 'script name' is '-c'.

With a script that echos the `sys.argv`:

```
1119:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py --test foobar
['echo.py', '--test', 'foobar']
```

Comment: Thank you, I get that usually sys.argv[0] is the program.
In this case, I would have expected it to be either `python` or `python -c`, not just `-c`.